# How to insert record (sql query) if not exist for specific value of a field in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table usersbooks:

```
idUser - int
idBook - int
bookSummary - text
```

and this situation:

```
idUser idBook bookSummary

   1     1       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser
   1     2       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser
   1     3       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser

   2     1       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser
   2     3       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser

   3     2       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser
   3     3       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser
```

I need to insert a record like

```
   #user #book initalInfoAboutTheBook
```

for each combination book user (with the corresponding initial infos), but some record are still there and must **NOT** be overwritten or updated for they could be different from the initial ones. Some are missing, like user 2 that has not book 2 and user 3 that has not book 1, and these are the one that must be inserted.

Assuming I can make several queries into a for cycle, one cycle for each book, like

```
"INSERT INTO usersbooks 
idBook='+idBook+' ..... "

with idBook 0 to 10, for example
```

what must be the INSERT query to get the desired result without touching the existing record?

```
idUser idBook bookSummary

   1     1       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser
   1     2       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser
   1     3       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser

   2     1       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser
   2     2       initalInfoAboutTheBook            (newly inserted!)
   2     3       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser

   3     1       initalInfoAboutTheBook            (newly inserted!)
   3     2       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser
   3     3       modifiedInfoAboutTheBookByTheUser
```

NB: There are TWO problems here: how to avoid touching existing record and how to execute the query for any user already present in the db

Comment: an INSERT never overwrites an existing record, it always creates a new one. If you want avoid inserting records with IDs which duplicate existing ones, then a) enforce that via primary key constraints and b) to avoid a constraint error then write a select statement to find out which ID combinations already exist, and don't run any insert statements for those IDs.

Comment: Not the insert query, you could create a compound unique key based on user and book then any attempt to insert would fail if the same user/book combination was found.

Comment: I don't user mysql - does it not support `where` in `insert`s? eg: `insert into books(bla,blah) values(blabla,blahblag) where not exists (select 1 from books where bloblahblah)`

Comment: Mysql does not support insert into books(bla,blah) values(blabla,blahblag) where not exists (select 1 from books where bloblahblah) as a matter of interest why did you think it might ?

Comment: `insert...where` Can you tell me which database platforms you've used which _do_ support this syntax? I've never come across any. It doesn't really make sense - a WHERE clause in SQL is about restricting the set of rows matched by the statement. But with an insert you're creating a new row, so there's nothing to match. As I mentioned above already, if you want to check whether a row with certain values already exists, you have to do it via a separate select statement, and then make a decision based on the result of that statement about whether to go ahead with your insert or not.

Comment: @P.Salmon you are right :) I was thinking postgres but then I checked my code and I was using `insert into ... select ... where ....` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0daf6b/1

Answer (score 1):

an easy solution can be this. 
you can try to make a **primary key** with the two fields idUser and idBook, 
then use an **Insert Ignore**. that way avoid the duplicate key error, and insert just when the primary key(the combination of that two ids) doesn't exists.

Comment: If you use the IGNORE modifier, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: yess.. and thats why i point **avoid the duplicate key error, and insert just when the primary key(the combination of that two ids) doesn't exists**

Comment: trying to build the query... Ok for the ignore and primary key, how can I execute the insert for every idUser present in the table?

Comment: if the point is that every record have an "initial value", then you can set the default value on the column definition. <br/> now, if you want to do a insert for records that already exists, then, can try an **insert select** and in the where of the select put a **subselect** to get the values of the table.

Comment: nope, the value are different from every book but the same for every user (and taken from a json). Still i miss the syntax to do that :) Thank you anyway